# can not ping as normal user in Docker centos image

Tags: centos, docker

My Dockerfile

```
FROM centos
RUN useradd me
CMD su -c "ping localhost" me
```

My test commands:

```
$ docker build -t test .
$ docker run --rm -it test
ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted

$ docker run --rm -it test /bin/bash    
[root@153c87b53b53 /]# ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.126 ms
```

My temp solution is https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=39341

```
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/ping
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a "temp solution" but the actual solution to allow user level pings - basically ping needs root level access to open up a socket in raw mode. So when it attempts to do this, but is not run as root, then you get the error above.

So in order for this to work, ping must be setuid root, which is what you are doing when you `chmod 4755 /bin/ping` - this means that when you run ping as a normal user, you elevate the privilege to root, but ping is smart enough to drop you back down to your user directly after opening the socket.

So your Dockerfile could look like this:

```
FROM centos
RUN chmod 4755 /bin/ping
RUN useradd me
CMD su -c "ping localhost" me
```